# Gridview display for lookup fields

Tags: sharepoint, gridview, lookup

I have a SPGridView that displays items from a list (using spboundfield).

the list has some lookupfields. and multi-lookup fileds in my SPGridview the filter values of a lookupfield appear in this format:

{id};#{Value}

what are my options now?

Answer (score 1):

for generating columns for `SPGridView`, need to use `SPBoundField`, instead `BoundField`!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template class for a template field, in that template class reformat the lookup field as you list, the simplest way is of course GetValueAsHtml of the SPField class.
Here is a good tutorial on generic templates: http://www.developer.com/article.php/3609991

Comment: Is there a way to use string.replace function to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dataviewwebpart class instead of spgridview to accomplish this. Using xslt you can access lots of libraries hat will assist you in your formatting. Marc d. Anderson has a great xslt functions library on codeplex called sharepoint xslt templates.

http://sympmarc.com/2010/04/22/new-codeplex-project-sharepoint-xsl-templates-spxslt/

Comment: I am trying to move away from Dataview wp because it has a issue with the sort. dvwp only sorts on displayed items as opposed to sorting the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members"> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString()) %> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code:

```
// Make sure declare using System.Text.RegularExpression; 
protected string RemoveCharacters(object String) { 
  string s1 = String.ToString(); 
  string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty); 
  newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " "); 
  return newString.ToString(); 
}
```